# Crystal Reports . Add a background image

Tags: sql, vb.net, crystal-reports, sql-server-2012, reportviewer

I am using Crystal reports for visual studio and i created a report that is needed to have a background image.I cant find a way to put a background image like Microsoft Report Viewer Report . Is there a way ?

Comment: are you displaying any data on image? or its just a image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no background image item in Crystal Reports.
Insert an image and "Send to back" to display it as a background image